# Which certificate I should use when submit to appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have confused which certificate I should use in order to make apple push notification available for my app when my app accepted in appstore.

I was able to send and receive notification when I run app from xcode , but people download app from appstore only can get access token , but the can not receive notification .

I have confused about certificate App ids , provision ... distribution ... production .... etc .

Which certificate I should convert it as .pem file in my server ?

Which certificate I should put it as provision file in xcode ?

Please note that any application run from xcode can get notifications , any application run from appstore cannot.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use your "Distribution Certificate" for Appstore upload.**

As of now I hope for testing you would have used development certificate. But while you push your app to Appstore you will be using "Distrubution Certificate" for uploading your app.

Like wise you have to create a push notification certificate for distribution(if in case you have it already make use of it) and convert that to .pem file to your server. Now push notification should work fine for AppStore upload.

Comment: I should use two distributions certificate ? One for distribution and the second for notification ? Or only one for both ?

Comment: Yes two distribution certificates. *IMPORTANT : Actually for uploading app you will be using a distribution certificate which is different from the push notification distribution certificate.